# Missing verb in off-topic reason

Tags: bug, status-completed

[image]

> *as it to attract*

should be something like:

> **as it *tends* to attract**

Comment: Or simply "as it attracts" and remove the "to"

Comment: Yeah, that. We were jumping on it to fit into character limit. I will edit when toscho is online because process needs two mods.

Comment: @GhostToast, great suggestion. I looked at what was missing, you did on what was superfluous ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rarst has rewritten the close reason now, using @GhostToast’s suggestion, and I have approved it.